# How to predict what stage of business cycle we are currently in based off of unemployment indicators

Tags: programming, prediction, financial-markets

I am trying to predict what part of the business cycle (Early, Mid, Late 1, Late 2) we are currently in by looking at unemployment indicators.

Qualitatively, I've reasoned that:

| . | Early | Mid | Late 1 | Late 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unemployment | Rising | Peak/Falling | Low/Falling | Low/(Steady Decline or Rising) |
| Change |  |  | level < prior 3m avg | level > prior 3m avg |
| z-score |  | level > 50th %tile(3yr or 7yr) | level < 50th %ile (3y or 7y) | <=25th %ile |

I am now trying to express this through code... I believe by taking the z-score I can try to predict what the current state of the business cycle we are in. I am unsure if there is a better calculation than z-score to predict this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Sahm Rule Recession Indicator? It indicates the start of a recession based on the unemployment rate. (Unfortunately for you I don't think there is a similar one for the end of a recession, at least I haven't heard of one).  It has been written up in many places https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SAHMREALTIME and may give you ideas...

Comment: @nbbo2 Thats actually an extremely fascinating indicator... Would you happen to know any similar ones that dont necessarily require the U3 numbers?